# Double generic constraint on class in Java: extends ConcreteClass & I

Tags: java, generics, constraints

Is there a way to define a generic constraint in Java which would be analogous to the following C# generic constratint ?

```
class Class1<I,T> where I : Interface1, Class2 : I
```

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
class Class1<I extends Interface1, T extends I & Class2>
```

But the compiler complains about the "Class2" part: Type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds.

Comment: `extands`? Did you mean `extends`? -- also the C# line does not place any restriction on the T type, perhaps you made a mistake?

Comment: This is a typo and this is Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I can see of resolving the Java code is to make Class2 an interface.

You cannot constrain a type parameter to extends more than one class or type parameter. Further, you can't use super here.

Comment: This is a good solution, theoretically, but the type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds. Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

This code compiles here fine:

```
interface Interface1 {}

class Class2 {}

class Class1<I extends Interface1, T extends Class2 & Interface1> {}
```

Why do you need the *I* type there when you assume only *Interface1* anyway? (you won't know anything more in your class about *I* than it extends *Interface1*)

Comment: The point is that "T extends Class2 & I" not "T extends Class2 & Interface1" when you specify concrete classes for both parameters