# How to force a generic type parameter to be an interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Is there a way in java to specify, that the type parameter of a generic class must be an interface (not just extending it!)

What I want to do is the following:

```
public class MyClass<X extends SomeInterface, Y extends SomeOtherClass & X>
```

Meaning that Y must be a subclass of SomeOtherClass AND implement X.
What I currently get by the compiler is

> The type X is not an interface; it cannot be specified as a bounded parameter

So, how can I tell the compiler that X must always be an interface?

**Edit:**
OK, I guess I oversimplified my problem a bit. Let's use my actual application domain to make it more clear:

I have an API for representing diagrams. A **Diagram** contains **Node** and **Edge** objects. All these three classes implement the **Shape** interface. Shapes may have child shapes, a parent shape and belong to a diagram.

The thing is, that I need to make two versions of this API: one open-source with just basic functionality and an extended one with more features. However, the extended API must only provide methods, which return the extended types (**ExtendedDiagram**, **ExtendedNode**, **ExtendedEdge** and (here comes the problem) **ExtendedShape**).
So I have something like this:

```
/* BASIC CLASSES */
public interface Shape<X extends Shape<X,Y>, Y extends Diagram<X,Y>>{
    public List<X> getChildShapes();
    public X getParent();
    public Y getDiagram();
    ...
}

public class Diagram<X extends Shape<X,Y>, Y extends Diagram<X,Y>> implements Shape<X,Y>{...}
public class Edge<X extends Shape<X,Y>, Y extends Diagram<X,Y>> implements Shape<X,Y>{...}
...

/* EXTENDED CLASSES */
public interface ExtendedShape extends Shape<ExtendedShape,ExtendedDiagram> { ... }

public class ExtendedDiagram extends Diagram<ExtendedShape,ExtenedDiagram> implements ExtendedShape { ... }
public class ExtendedEdge extends Edge<ExtendedShape,ExtenedDiagram> implements ExtendedShape { ... }
...
```

The extended API works fine and the basic API code gives some warnings, but the main problem occurs when using the basic API:

```
public class SomeImporter<X extends Shape<X,Y>, Y extends Diagram<X,Y>, E extends Edge<X,Y>>{
    private Y diagram;

    public void addNewEdge(E newEdge){
        diagram.addChildShape(newEdge);
    ...
```

That last line gives me the following warning:

> The method addChildShape(X) in the type Diagram is not applicable for the arguments (E)

So now, I would just like to specify that E also needs to implement X and all would be fine - I hope ;)

Does all that make sense? Do you guys know a way to do that? Or is there even a better way to get the extended API with the said restrictions?
Thanks for sticking with me, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132353/double-generic-constraint-on-class-in-java-extends-concreteclass-i

Comment: That error is a bit incorrect. It really means that you need to refer to a real class or interface and NOT another generic type (i.e. `Y extends SomeOtherClass & SomeInterface`, as pointed out in the link provided by @Yochai Timmer)

Comment: But that's the thing: I need a generic, because I already have a subinterface of SomeInterface (lets call it ExtendedInterface). MyClass is sometimes used with SomeInterface and sometimes with ExtendedInterface. Additionally, there might well be other extensions of SomeIterface in the future...

Maybe I simplified my probem statement a trifle too much, I'll edit my original question.

Comment: Can you add the method signature for your addNewEdge? - side note: That one very complicated sets of Generics that you use there, dont you get dizzy?

Comment: You can see the method signature for addNewEdge in my edited posts. If you mean addChildShape then that would be:  
public void addChildShape(X newShape); (in the Shape interface defined above)

Comment: And yes, it is quite complex. Especially considering the fact that I only want to get the right return types ;)

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

```
class Foo<T extends Number & Comparable> {...}
```

A class Foo with one type parameter, T. Foo must be instantiated with a type that is a subtype of Number and that implements Comparable.

Comment: Can't say that you're wrong, but it doesn't solve my problem. If you look at the problem statement again, then you'll see that I used just that construct in the first line. It seems that the current Java standard just doesn't allow for a generic type parameter after the '&', but that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6):

In the generics context, `<Type extends IInterface>` handles both extends and implements. Here's an example:

```
public class GenericsTest<S extends Runnable> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericsTest<GT> t = new GenericsTest<GT>();
        GenericsTest<GT2> t2 = new GenericsTest<GT>();
    }
}

class GT implements Runnable{
    public void run() {

    }
}

class GT2 {

}
```

GenericsTest will accept GT because it implements Runnable. GT2 does not, therefore it fails when trying to compile that second GenericsTest instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the point I was trying to make.
What I want to have is a generic type parameter (in your case 'S'), which must be an interface. 
So both your classes 'GT' and 'GT2' would fail the compilation. An Interface 'Executable' with: "interface Executable extends Runnable" would pass

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simplify your model a bit: too much generics become quickly a real pain in terms of readability, and that's quite an issue if you define a public API. Usually, if you can't understand anymore what should be inside the brackets, then you're going too far for your need - and you can't expect users to understand it better than yourself...

Anyway, in order to make your code compile, you may try defining something like this, in the `Shape` type:

```
public <S extends Shape<?,?>> void addChildShape(S shape);
```

That should do it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your comments concerning too much generics are quite right. Unfortunately - as I mentioned to @nbryant - my Dogs' children need to be Dogs; when I move the generics down to method-level, then I can't be sure of the correct return types (someone may add a type of child that's different to the one I try to get).

Comment: You don't need to avoid inserting the wrong types: you just need to expose the appropriate interface to your users, so a `List<Shape>` may as well contain `ExtendedShape`s as long as clients only see them as simple `Shape`s... Furthermore, clients with no access to extended features surely are not able to build `ExtendedShape`s to add them to such a List.

Comment: My problem is rather the other way around: I'm mainly using the extended classes, but can't just always cast elements of a list to the extended class. One of the might just be a simple class. Plus it is an inconvenience having to cast to extended classes on each method call.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the following:

```
public interface Shape<X extends Shape<X,Y>, Y extends Diagram<X,Y>>{
    public List<X> getChildShapes();
    public X getParent();
    public Y getDiagram();
    ...
}
```

I would advise, at the minimum, getting rid of the X type variable, as follows:

```
public interface Shape<Y>{
    public List<Shape<Y>> getChildShapes();
    public Shape<Y> getParent();
    public Diagram<Y> getDiagram();
    ...
}
```

The reason being is that what you originally wrote suffers from a potentially unbounded recursive nesting of the type parameters. A shape may be nested within a parent shape, which may be nested within another, all of which must be accounted for in the type signature... not a good recipe for readability. Well, it doesn't happen quite that way in your example, in which you declare "Shape<X>" instead of "Shape<Shape<X>>" but that's the direction you're going in, if you ever wanted to actually use Shape on its own...

I would probably also recommend going one step further and getting rid of the Y variable for similar reasons. Java generics don't cope very well with this sort of composition. When attempting to enforce static types for this type of modelling via generics, I've found that the type system starts to break down when you start to extend things later on.

It's typical of the Animal/Dog problem... Animal has a getChildren(), but Dog's children must also be Dogs... Java doesn't cope with this well because (in part due to the lack of abstract types as in languages like Scala, but I'm not saying you should rush off and use Scala for this problem either) the type variables have to start being declared in all sorts of places where they don't really belong.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. My problem here is that my Dog's children must be Dogs. It's a requirement. I've developed the code a bit further using my initial approach. I have subclasses, code that uses the generic classes and code that uses the subclasses and aside from some necessary casts it seems to work fine. I guess I'll just stick with it...

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre-processor to generate the "reduced" version of your code. Using apt and annotations might be a nice way to do it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that would work as I've never used apt before. I suspect that it might be a bit overkill for the use case, but as I said I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I might be WAY off base here, but my understanding of generics is a little different.

I am asking someone to correct me if I am wrong.

IMO -

This is a very confusing structure that you have.  You have SubClasses of Shape being referenced infinitely it looks like.

Your Shape interface is utilized in the same manner as a HashMap, but I have never seen a HashMap do what you are trying to do, eventually you have to have X be a class in Shape.  Otherwise you are doing HashMap

If you always want X to be a "IS A" relationship to an interface it won't happen.  That is not what generics are for.  Generics are used to apply methods to multiple Objects, and interfaces cannot be Objects.  Interfaces define a contract between a client and a class.  All you can do with the  is say that you will accept any Object that implements Runnable, because all or some of your methods are required to utilize the Runnable interface methods.  Otherwise if you don't specify  and you define as , then your contract between your class with the client can produce unexpected behavior and cause either the wrong return value or an exception to be thrown.

For example:

```
public interface Animal {
    void eat();

    void speak();
}

public interface Dog extends Animal {
    void scratch();

    void sniff();
}

public interface Cat extends Animal {
    void sleep();

    void stretch();
}

public GoldenRetriever implements Dog {
    public GoldenRetriever() { }

    void eat() {
        System.out.println("I like my Kibbles!");
    }

    void speak() {
        System.out.println("Rufff!");
    }

    void scratch() {
        System.out.println("I hate this collar.");
    }

    void sniff() {
        System.out.println("Ummmm?");
    }
}

public Tiger implements Cat {
    public Tiger() { }

    void eat() {
        System.out.println("This meat is tasty.");
    }

    void speak() {
        System.out.println("Roar!");
    }

    void sleep() {
        System.out.println("Yawn.");
    }

    void stretch() {
        System.out.println("Mmmmmm.");
    }
}
```

Now if you did this class you can expect that you CAN always call 'speak()' & 'sniff()'

```
public class Kingdom<X extends Dog> {
    public Kingdom(X dog) {
        dog.toString();
        dog.speak();
        dog.sniff();
    }
}
```

However, if you did this you CANNOT ALWAYS call 'speak()' & 'sniff()'

```
public class Kingdom<X> {
    public Kingdom(X object) {
        object.toString();
        object.speak();
        object.sniff();
    }
}
```

CONCLUSION:

Generics give you the ability to utilize methods on a wide range of objects, not interfaces.  Your final entry into a generic MUST be a type of Object.

Comment: I'm afraid that your conclusion is not quite right. AFAIK you can have 
`public interface Poodle extends Dog;
public class StandardPoodle implements Poodle` and using
`public class Kingdom<X extends Dog>` you could do
`Kingdom<Poodle> myPoodle = new Kindom<Poodle>(new StandardPoodle());`

So, what I would like to do with Java would be:
`public class Kingdom<X extends Animal, Y extends SomeClass & X>{
    public Kingdom(Y object){
        object.eat();
        //further code using SomceClass functionality
    }`

Comment: Your statement is false.  Generics checks for this case.  X must be the same class in all cases for the method.  The compiler would throw an error because StandardPoodle is not a Poodle in this case.  This is the main reason to use generics, it provides type safety while compiling.

Comment: Have you tried it? I just did! My Eclipse compiler didn't complain and the StandardPoodle sniffed like a Dog ;)

Comment: @Philipp, you win.  I'll try to explain it better when I get a chance.  Off the top of my head I am loss for words...:\

Answer (score 0):

The reserved word “extends” as along with a type parameter T is used to specify a bound.

‘…in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).’ 
 [ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html ]

In short, “extends” can only be used to specify a bound (whether a class or an interface) for some class type parameter T and not any interface type parameter T.
In your case,

public class MyClass<X extends SomeInterface, Y extends SomeOtherClass & X>

The compiler resolves X to be a class. For the second occurrence of X along with the type parameter Y (which clearly needs to be a class anyway), it requires X to be an interface. Since it has already resolved X to be class, it signals the error for the second occurrence of X,

The type X is not an interface;

Further, had X been specified in the first occurrence as an unbounded parameter, the compiler would have resolved it to be either a class or an interface and it would’ve considered the second occurrence of X to be a possible interface and thus allowed compilation. Since it was not so, the compiler clarifies,

it cannot be specified as a bounded parameter